# Element not traversable- closest facility -one way roads?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, network-analyst, network-dataset

I am trying to write an ArcPy script using the closet facility option to find the closet facilities (with minutes as a cost attribute) for vehicles.

I have a problem that all the incidents along the one-way roads, are considered as not traversable locations, I have read here about this problem and there is a suggestion that the problem in the FT or TF of the one-way roads.

How can I solve this problem, as the line for making the closet facility layer is as follows:

```
arcpy.MakeClosestFacilityLayer_na(inputNetworkDataset, Closest_Facility, "MINUTES", "TRAVEL_FROM", "", "1", "", "ALLOW_UTURNS", "", "USE_HIERARCHY", "", "TRUE_LINES_WITH_MEASURES", "", "NOT_USED") #
```

as the input network dataset is adjusted with restriction (roads direction), cost attribute (minutes) and hierarchy?

Comment: Anyone can help or have suggestions regards this problem?